# Infinite Board: Conway's Game of Life - Python

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I was assigned this project with instructions below:

> The game of Life is defined for an infinite-sized grid. In Chapter 2, we defined the Life Grid ADT to use a fixed-size grid in which the user specified the width and height of the grid. This was sufficient as an illustration of the use of a 2-D array for the implementation of the game of Life. But a full implementation should allow for an infinite-sized grid. Implement the Sparse Life Grid ADT using an approach similar to the one used to implement the sparse matrix.

I honestly don't really understand the concept that well. Could you please give me a brief description (if not brief code) that a layman can understand? I would appreciate it.

Sparselifegrid.py

```
""" My initial GameOfLife code
    Feb 27, 2013
    Sparse Matrix code specially designed for Game of Life
"""
class SparseLifeGrid:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        "pass" just allows this to run w/o crashing.
        Replace it with your own code in each method.
        """
        pass 

    def minRange(self):
        """
        Return the minimum row & column as a list.
        """
        pass

    def maxRange(self):
        """
        Returns the maximum row & column as a list.
        """
        pass 

    def configure(self,coordList):
        pass 

    def clearCell(self,row, col):
        pass 

    def setCell(self,row, col):
        pass 

    def isValidRowCol(val1,val2):
        pass 

    def isLiveCell(self,row, col):
        pass 

    def numLiveNeighbors(self, row,col):
        pass 


    def __getitem__(self,ndxTuple):
        pass 

    def __setitem__(self,ndxTuple, life):
        """
        The possible values are only true or false:
        True says alive, False for dead.
        """
        pass 

    def _findPosition(self,row,col):
        pass 

    def __repr__(self):
        pass 

    def __str__(self):
        """
        This method will only print the non-empty values,
        and a row and column outside the non-empty values.
        """
        pass 

    def evolve(self):
        """
        Return the next generation state.
        """
        pass 

    def hasOccurred(self):
        """
        Check whether  this current state has already occured.
        If not, return False.  If true, return which generation number (1-10).
        """
        pass 

    def __eq__(self,other):
        """
        This is good method if we want to compare two sparse matrices.
        You can just use sparseMatrixA == sparseMatrixB because of this method. 
        """
        pass

    def printLifeGrid(lifeGrid):
        """
        Print a column before and after the live cells
        """
        s=""
        maxRange=lifeGrid.maxRange()
        minRange=lifeGrid.minRange()
        for i in range(minRange[0]-1,maxRange[0]+2):
            for j in range(minRange[1]-1,maxRange[1]+2):
                s+=" "+str(lifeGrid[i,j])
            s+="\n"
        print(s)


class _GoLMatrixElement:
    """
    Storage class for one cell
    """
    def __init__(self,row,col):
        pass 

    def __str__self(self):
        pass 

    def __eq__(self,other):
        pass
```

Here's my main file

```
""" Marcus Brown's  initial GameOfLife code
    Feb 27, 2013
"""
from SparseLifeGrid_Key import SparseLifeGrid
import sys


# You'll probably need to add some other stuff like global variables


""" ####################################################
        Don't change anything below this line: readPoints or main
""" ####################################################

def readPoints(lifeGrid):
    """
    Reads the locations of life and set to the SparseMatrix
    """
    print("1. Enter positions of life with row,col format (e.g., 2,3).")
    print("2. Enter empty line to stop.")

    life=input()
    coordList=[]
    while life:
        points=life.split(",")
        try:    
            coord=[int(points[0]),int(points[1])]
            coordList.append(coord)
        except ValueError:
            print("Ignored input:" + life+ ", row, col not valid numbers")
        except:
                print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("added, keep entering or enter empty line to stop.")
        life=input()
    print("Thanks, finished entering live cells")
    lifeGrid.configure(coordList)




def main():
    """
    Runs for ten generations if a stable (repeating) state is not found.
    """
    lifeGrid= SparseLifeGrid()
    readPoints(lifeGrid)
    lifeGrid.printLifeGrid()
    patterns=0
    i=0
    while i <10 and patterns == 0:
        """
        Evolve to the next generation
        """
        lifeGrid.evolve()
        """
        Check whether this generation is a repetition of any of the
        previous states.
        If yes return the previous matching generation (1-10).
        """
        patterns=lifeGrid.hasOccurred()
        if patterns != -1:
            break
        i+=1
        lifeGrid.printLifeGrid()

    if i==10:
        print("No pattern found")
    else: 

        print("Pattern found at: " + str(i)+ " of type: " + str(patterns))

main()
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Bear in mind we can help you with practical matters of code here, not so much with CS theory or code reviews. We have other sites in the SE network for that.

Comment: Do you understand what a sparse matrix is, or how one might go about representing one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sparse matrix is a representation of a matrix where only the locations of values not equal to the default (usually 0) are stored in memory. A simple way to represent such a matrix in Python is to use a dictionary where the key is a tuple of coordinate `(x, y)` and the value is the matrix values.

For example, this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

could have the following representation:

```
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
sparse_matrix = {(1, 2): 1}
```

and you would access the values like that:

```
for x in xrange(4):
  for y in xrange(4):
      assert matrix[y][x] == sparse_matrix.get((x, y), 0)
```

This should be enough to get you started. Your exercise want you to wrap such a sparse matrix in a class that will give it the same interface as a traditional matrix.

There are more advanced way to store such [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), each doing a different trade off between complexity, memory usage, ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess I thought I knew what a sparse matrix was, but I didn't. May I ask you for help if I get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple sparse matrix based game of life solution in Python 2.x.  You can set the size to as large as your system can handle. It wraps around in both the x and y direction:

```
class Cell():
    def __init__(self, x, y, live=True):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.live = live
        self.around = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y)

    def spawn(self):
        self.live = True
        self.around = 0
        return self

class Grid():
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.xMax = width
        self.yMax = height
        self.cells = []
        self.deltas = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1), (1, 0),
                      (1, 1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0)]

    def tick(self):
        newCells = self.cells[:]
        ''' create potential new cells '''
        for cell in self.cells:
            for dx, dy in self.deltas:
                newCell = Cell((cell.x+dx)%self.xMax,
                               (cell.y+dy)%self.yMax, live=False)
                if newCell not in newCells:
                    newCells.append(newCell)
                newCells[newCells.index(newCell)].around += 1
        ''' spawn new cells for next grid '''
        self.cells = []
        for cell in newCells:
            if (cell.live and cell.around in [2, 3]
            or not cell.live and cell.around == 3):
                self.cells.append(cell.spawn())

    def show(self):
        for y in range(self.yMax):
            print ''.join('X|' if Cell(x, y) in self.cells
                     else ' |' for x in range(self.xMax))
        print
```

Usage:

```
>>> glider = [Cell(2,0), Cell(2,1), Cell(2,2), Cell(1,2), Cell(0,1)]
>>> g = Grid(7, 7)
>>> glider = [Cell(2,0), Cell(2,1), Cell(2,2), Cell(1,2), Cell(0,1)]
>>> g.cells = glider
>>> g.show()
 | |X| | | | |
X| |X| | | | |
 |X|X| | | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |

>>> g.tick()
>>> g.tick()
>>> g.show()
 | |X| | | | |
 | | |X| | | |
 |X|X|X| | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |

>>> g.tick()
>>> g.tick()
>>> g.show()
 | | | | | | |
 | | |X| | | |
 |X| |X| | | |
 | |X|X| | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | |
```